# JMS Cache Level Setting from properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-jms

I have defined `jms.listen.cache.level = 1` in properties file as below:

```
jms.listen.get.timeOut = 30000
#conn = 1, session = 2, cunsumer = 3,none = 0
jms.listen.chache.level = 1
jms.concurrency.datapoint.request=10
```

And Below is the application-context.xml file where i have defined this.

```
<bean id="DataPointRequest:messageListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer" scope="prototype">
        <property name="autoStartup" value="false" />
        <property name="receiveTimeout" value="${jms.listen.get.timeOut}"></property>
        <property name="cacheLevel" value="${jms.listen.chache.level}"></property>
        <property name="concurrency" value="${jms.concurrency.datapoint.request}" />
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="DataPointRequest:connectionFactory"/>
        <property name="destination" ref="DataPointRequest:requestDestination"/>
        <property name="messageListener" ref="DataPointRequest:messageListener" />
        <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
        <property name="errorHandler" ref="jmsErrorHandler"/>
    </bean>
```

When I run my application it prints `[...JMSMessageListeningInboundEndpoint] (main) cacheLevel=3`. Which is CACHE_CONSUMER = 3 value defined in `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` class. 
As transaction manager is not set here that's why It takes `CACHE_CONSUMER` value and prints cacheLevel = 3 in start of application. Then It prints `[...JMSMessageListeningInboundEndpoint] (main) cacheLevel=1`.

I want to set cacheLevel = 1 in start of application also. How to do this ? Kindly suggest me.

Below is the class where I get cacheLevel = 3 in start of application.

```
public class JMSMessageListeningInboundEndpoint implements InboundEndpoint {

    private AbstractMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer;
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JMSMessageListeningInboundEndpoint.class);

    @Override
    public void start() throws StartInboundEndpointException {

        try {

            messageListenerContainer.start();
            if(messageListenerContainer  instanceof org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer){
                int cacheLevel = ((org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer)messageListenerContainer).getCacheLevel();
                logger.info("cacheLevel=" + cacheLevel + ".");
            }

        } catch (JmsException e) {
            throw new StartInboundEndpointException("Failed to start message listener container.", this, "start_failed", e);
        }
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        messageListenerContainer.shutdown();
    }

    public void setMessageListenerContainer(
            AbstractMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer) {
        this.messageListenerContainer = messageListenerContainer;

    }
}
```

Comment: Why that contraption... Just use `${jms.listen.chache.level}` as the value in your xml configuration of the message listener. Don't use the contraption you have now, use the normal configuration mechanism.

Comment: Then it should be set, why is it `prototype` scoped? The contraption with the `InboundEndpoint` what is the use of that? Hence contraption. Also please don't add code as comments, use it to improve your question, in comments it isn't readable. Update your question with it.

Comment: Hello Deinum, What do you mean by contraption here. I have already defined this in XML as below:                                                                                <property name="cacheLevel" value="${jms.listen.chache.level}"></property>